# hide part of text in html using css

Tags: css

When I have the following code, how do I hide the 5000 and 5001 text using css?

```
<div id="field-dishe" class="readonly_label">
5000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;家乡猪脚醋  或  秘制黄酒鸡 Pork Trotters in Sweetened Vinegar Or Chicken Stewed in Rice Wine<br> 
5001&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;椰香冷当雞 Rendang Chicken<br>
</div>
```

Edit: It is difficult to wrap it with span because they are generated by a framework.

Comment: Using just css, without JavaScript nor HTML change ?

Comment: wrap 5000 and 5001 in a span and add display none to that span. .readonly_label span { display:none; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just CSS, without JavaScript and without changing the HTML, it's hard to do it without ugly hacks like this one :

```
#field-dishe{
  position: relative;
}
#field-dishe:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    background: white;
    content:" "
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/onodoFu/4/)

I'd recommend to change your HTML by adding some span or to use JavaScript. Here's an example with jQuery :

```
$('#field-dishe').html(function(_,h){
  return h.replace(/\d+/g,'');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/onodoFu/3/)

Comment: hi dystroy, i cannot have the height fixed as the list will be different each time.

Comment: @redcoder I edited with a not fixed height. But really, I'm not sure changing the HTML or adding some JS wouldn't be cleaner. Having a fixed width would be painful when you change your font size or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

not really possible with just css

Why not alter the html a bit (*by wrapping those parts in `span` elements*)

```
<div id="field-dishe" class="readonly_label">
<span>5000</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;家乡猪脚醋  或  秘制黄酒鸡 Pork Trotters in Sweetened Vinegar Or Chicken Stewed in Rice Wine<br> 
<span>5001</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;椰香冷当雞 Rendang Chicken<br>
</div>
```

and use `#field-dishe span{display:none}`

---

In the future if the CSS3 text-indent draft is implemented you will be able to do

```
#field-dishe{
  text-indent:-42px each-line;
}
```

Documentation at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#text-indent

Comment: can't you use display:none to hide the entire div?

Comment: @john, the OP specifically asks how to hide the 5000 and 5001 text inside the element.. not the whole element..