# Can one hide the second character in a span with CSS?

Tags: css, hidden, weebly

I am building an e-commerce site with Weebly, for use in France.

Weebly, by default, provides prices in a span tag:

```
<span class="xxx"> €200.20 </span>
```

**The Euro should come after the price, not before like the dollar.** I can add a Euro sign at the end with content: "€", but **I need to get rid of the leading Euro sign.**

I have no access to the backend to add or change the tags -- I'm stuck trying to change the content of the tag via CSS (which I know is verboten).

Tragically, the Euro is the second character and not the first, so I can't directly manipulate it.

**A possible solution would be to shift the content of the span tag to the left, cutting off the Euro sign.**

*Other solutions are welcome.*

I'm not optimistic, and since the site template already has tons of complicated javascript I'd prefer to avoid using a scripting solution.

Before marking this question as a duplicate: many people have asked how to manipulate first words in CSS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, but it requires to make `<span>` block or inline-block

```css
.xxx:first-letter {
  color: transparent;
}
.xxx {
  display: inline-block;
}
.xxx:after {
  content: "€";
}
```

```html
<span class="xxx"> €200.20 </span>
```

It won't work with multiple prices. I think you need javascript to achieve that.

Comment: The problem is that the € is the SECOND character (after a space), so I can't use first-letter. But it would be a good solution in any other case.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834795/hide-part-of-text-in-html-using-css), I was able to solve my problem temporarily with this code:

```
.xxx{
  position:relative;
  left:-10px;
}

.xxx:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:2;
  background: white;
  content:" "
}
```

Since it's dependent on font size and width, it's not a good solution. And in my case, there are other cases where there are multiple prices in the same span (€100-€200) that I won't be able to fix.